# Keras: display model shape in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code which I used to view my Network architecture.

[image]

However, I also want to see the shape of each layer, so I tried to use the following:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
#plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, to_file='model.png')
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

The output file 'model.png' looks fine. But I am unable to make it display in the Jupyter Notebook. Any idea what I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

since the resulting image is not a svg file anymore you should replace `SVG` with `Image`
use

```
from IPython.display import Image 
... 

plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, to_file='model.png')
Image('model.png')
```